# Running PHP code from remote server?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, remote-access

I want to prevent access to the functions file in my Wordpress theme. I thought to hide functions.php by putting it on my server and calling it from the client's server. Is that a workable solution? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is technically possible if your client's server [has allow_url_include set.](http://php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php) However, it's still a bad idea for four reasons:

- **Speed:** opening another HTTP request and waiting for it to complete every time anyone views your client's site will get slow very fast. It'll also hammer your site.
- **Security:** The PHP file on the remote server (your server, in this case) will need to be printed in plaintext. This could be a bad thing, particularly if you've written customized, potentially-insecure code in it. Coincidentally, this also means that your approach **won't actually stop your client from finding out what the script does.** There's also nothing stopping the client from loading the URL of your unprotected script, pasting it into his WordPress directory, and altering the `include`. Additionally, if your server is ever compromised or someone snatches your domain, they can then inject code onto your client's server with impunity.
- **Ethics:** Unless your client is explicitly made aware of this arrangement, it is unethical because if your business relationship terminates he or she will still be vulnerable to code injection, even after terminating your FTP/SSH/WordPress dashboard access.
- **Reliability:** If you do this, any time your site is offline your client's site will die with a messy error message.

Re-homing executable code on your server is probably a really bad idea, and while it is absolutely technically possible, there are many compelling reasons why doing things this way are a bad idea.

If you are trying to protect proprietary code from the client, your only good options are to:

1. **Host his site yourself.** This could be profitable down the line if your technology is something that a specialized hosting company could be built around.
2. **Build an API** that can grant metered access to your proprietary data or processing, and write a WordPress plugin to talk to the API. This could be profitable down the line both by encouraging developers to write software for your system, and the WordPress plugin would lower the barrier for entry to doing business with you.

Comment: I have to agree especially with the Ethics bullet point.  This would have to be spelled out explicitly within your contract, along with a detailed plan of what would happen should your server be down, causing their site not to function properly.  By trying to host the functions.php on your own, I think you are opening the door for a whole world of possible problems to befall should something go wrong.  Especailly when there is money involved.

Comment: Thanks sudowned your help is very appreciated and i am totally agree with your opinions.
Can you please give me a clear guide for the API option that you mentioned and the availability of this option with the wordpress.

Answer (score 2):

Why not change permissions? You could also move it to a non-public part of the directory tree and place a fwd file and code. That is how I use wp-config.  I don't see why you couldn't do that with functions.php

Comment: It's not your fault I guess, but how the OP asks the question, it looks like something questionable at all. Your answer is however technically correct, so it gets my +1, however it might never be accepted as an answer because OP is actually looking for something different (and not asking in a good way about it). So not your fault, you're new, you get a +1 for answering. I suggest you pick better questions the next time for answers (just a tip).

Answer (score 1):

You can just put a .htaccess rule that redirects /functions.PHP to your homepage. This is what Facebook does.

Edit: see my comment below.

Comment: Hovever if your server is down then the client can't access their web either... You're not FB I mean...

Comment: Sorry, only just realised what you actually meant. As jtheman states, you'll have a lot of responsibility, not to mention bandwidth. If you're creating a theme for sale, or a paid website, just accept that it may be thieves. All the theme websites do it this way. Just minify and anonimyze functions if you want added security.